# .htaccess rewrite fancy rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

I am trying to make fancy url,
I read a lot on it but had no luck so far in implementing it successfully.

```
 http://www.domain.com/name-any-name-name-any-free-3034-dev.htm
```

current url is

```
 http://www.domain.com/dev.php?id=3034
```

my htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)([^-]*)-dev\.htm$ /dev.php?id=$1 [L]
```

which rule put for work this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.+-([0-9]+)-dev\.htm$ /dev.php?id=$2 [L]
```